GS013 when trying to execute signed transaction bundle on a replayed Polygon safe with CLI
Background
A safe{wallet} v1.3.0 has been created as a replay on Polygon.

Original ETH: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf865ee51a250705ac56df242608a0830d1d084d0b41f48b66ccf881fe4f015a0

Replayed Polygon L2:
https://polygonscan.com/tx/0xffed0ea61896b9b28142bdd29792da8d2fa919744c96f4ee7dd67cfdff32249c#eventlog


What are trying to achieve
We need to transfer ownership of a contract that this safe is owner of. To achieve it we identified two paths:
1/ Directly call the transferOwnership method.
2/ Update the old signers to new ones and assess from there.
What is blocking us
As 1/ Tx simulation failed we bundled 2 swapOwners and changeThreshold: https://app.safe.global/transactions/queue?safe=matic:0x088a012BF6d510aa923c814eA83807f75F7061A0
Whenever using the safe-cli we get an error GS013.
oddly enough as the transactions are pending to be executed the signer configuration is not matching the original state anymore (both on webUI and CLI).
Would executing update_version_to_l2 help?
If so does the deletion of the offchain transaction with nonce 0 allow us to update via cli?

Updating to L2 version would not help you solve the problem. Could you detail exactly what you were trying to do when having the error GS013 ? what do you mean also by "the signer configuration is not matching the original state"? Please add as much detail as possible (including transaction hashes) in order to best support on this. Thanks in advance
